# I'm getting a ClassCastException event though the types are the same. Why?

Tags: java, class, exception, casting

I am not too new to Java, though I have never really worked with `Set`s before,
so can anybody please help me out here?

I'm having the following problem;
but first of all, this is my code:

```
HashMap<Position[], String> save = io.getSave();

Position[][] saved_pos = (Position[][]) save.keySet().toArray();
```

Though on the second line, Java throws a `ClassCastException`, but why?
Obviously, the Array returned by `save.keySet().toArray()` does contain `Position[][]`s, even though, unfortunately, `toArray()` in the class `Set` does only return an `Object[]` array.

So what can I do, I NEED to cast this.

Comment: I am interested to know why u are using position has your key.  Aka Why are you doing `HashMap<Position[], String>` and not `HashMap<String, Position[]>`  ?

Comment: what is the meaning of 2 dimensional array Position [][]?

Comment: @hovanessyan: It means an array whose elements have type `Position[]`. (A "jagged array", in other words.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `toArray()` method doesn't actually know that it's being called on a set of `Position[]`s; all it knows is that it's being called on a set. (This is because of how generics are implemented in Java; not very much information is available at run-time.) So, it just returns an `Object[]` full of `Partition[]`s, rather than returning a true `Partition[][]`. (The difference being that an `Object[]` *can* contain arbitrary objects — it would be valid, after your call, to write `saved_pos[0] = new Object()` — whereas a true `Partition[][]` would raise a `ArrayStoreException` if you tried to set one of its elements to `new Object()`.)

Fortunately, there's a separate `toArray(...)` method that can be used, where you *tell* it what array type you want, like so:

```
Position[][] saved_pos = save.keySet().toArray(new Position[0][]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
    Set<Position[]> positions = save.keySet();
    Position[][] saved_pos = positions.toArray(new Position[positions.size()][]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Position[][] saved_pos = save.keySet().toArray(new Position[0][])
```

You need this because Java can't cast `Object[][]` to `Position[][]`.

Answer (score 0):

The default toArray just returns you an Object and not Position, you will have to pass the type of Object you want toArray to return you,

Your code will be modified as

```
save.keySet().toArray(new Position[][]{}); // Yes a blank Position[][] will do
```